# The next door condominium HOA refuses to cut back 20'-30' high bushes that blocks my view. What action can I take to have them cut back these bushes

Tags: property

These enormous fast-growing thorn-covered bushes are in places 4' feet over my property line.  Besides being up to 30' high, they block my view of the horizon and foothills. My HOA has contacted the condominium's HOA on several occasions and they outright refuse to do anything about this issue. There has been a 'red flag' fire warning for our general area and I believe these bushes also present a fire hazard. Six months ago, I paid a landscape company $300 to cut back the bushes by 5'.  Is there anything I can do at this point? Thank you, jim

Comment: Voting to close.  [Questions that clearly ask for specific legal advice are off-topic for Law Stack Exchange.](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221/10281)

Comment: What jurisdiction are you in?

Comment: Hey there, welcome to Law Stack Exchange! Your question seems to be asking for specific legal advice. For that, you're best off speaking with a lawyer in your jurisdiction. Most lawyers offer free consultations during which you can discuss with them what options may be available to you.

Answer (score 3):

You can trim bushes at your property line, as you have done. There is little hope for forcing a neighbor to cut more radically on their side. It is possible that a fire ordinance could be an issue, so it the bushes are a credible fire-related threat to property, the fire department might intervene (your belief that the bushes pose a threat is countered by their presumed belief that there is no threat). There may be local plant-height ordinance, but perhaps bushes are restricted by local regulations, so check whether they are in violation there (a rather remote possibility). Finally, there could be view-protecting ordinances or CCRs, but again those are rare.